# Trying to redirect parent pages to child pages using 301 redirects

Tags: http-status-code-301

We're trying to redirect parent pages to their first child - our CMS (Concrete5) does this but the parent page is still accessible via the URL (and Google) so we're trying to use a 301 as well.

Here's an example of the paths we're we're trying to redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /events/show-name/ /events/show-name/exhibit/
```

How do we do this without having the redirects loop continuously? Happy to have multiple redirects for each parent page (there are only 3 of them) if that's easier.

Comment: Why do they loop continuously?

Comment: I don't know, but in the browser window we see an error and the exhibit portion of the URL loops like this:````/exhibit/exhibit/exhibit/exhibit/````